# Replace a field with a value in the input data

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a data

`A     BC      3       CD`

note that the spaces in between the fields are not constant

Now I want to replace the third field with another number which is stored in another variable v. 
I have used awk in this way:

```
echo "A     BC      3       CD" | awk '{$3 = $v; print}'
```

The output is the third field is getting replaced with the entire line(wrong output)
Is there any possible to get the desired output without changing the spaces in the original data?
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Try `echo "A BC 3 CD" | awk '{$3 = "'"$v"'"; print}'` In your code, `$v` is being evaluated by `awk`. With `v=0`. Hence `$3` gets replaced by `$0`, which is entire line.

Comment: `sed 's/\(\(\S*\s*\)\{2\}\)\S*/\1'"$v"'/'`

Comment: @anishsane ......your solution is adding an extra field with the value stored in $v along with original data like this:
A BC 3 4 CD
also please let me know if there is any way to replace the field without altering the number of spaces between each field
thanks in advance!!

Comment: @123 ........Sed command given by you may work for me.....but i need to make some changes in the syntax according to my requirement. Can you please explain the syntax??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ v=25
$ echo "A     BC      3       CD" | gawk '{print gensub(/[^ \t]+/, v, 3)}' v="$v"
A     BC      25       CD
```

In your code, `$v` is being evaluated by `awk`, not `bash`, with `v=0`. Hence `$3` gets replaced by `$0`, which is entire line.

Note that `gensub` is `gawk` enhancement...

Comment: @123 .......gawk seems to be unavailable......i forgot to mention that it is a solaris machine...apologies!!